# How can I shrink a VMware multi-volume disk?

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, virtual-disk

I'm familiar with shrinking the total space of a virtual disk on Oracle VirtualBox using their `vboxmanage.exe` command line tool for shrinking. 
Now I have a VMware multi-volume disk (vmdk), and I've defragmented and zeroed the free space of the OS/disk, but now I don't know how to proceed to shrink the total virtual-disk space to its real size like in VirtualBox.

Which tool I need to use?

Alternative to Workstation in case of that program is needed for shrinking, I'm using the VMware free player.

(I've seen [this solution](https://superuser.com/questions/611955/vmware-workstation-how-to-reduce-vmdk-maximum-size), but it uses the huge and paid Workstation program.)

I really don't want to depend on a program of that measures to accomplish this task.

Comment: Have you tried using the command "vmware-vdiskmanager -k myDisk.vmdk" to shrink the vmdk file? and also noticed that this command already available in the link you have mentioned.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I just did a trick and worked perfectlly.

1) Install **VMWare Workstation** in a VirtualMachine (to avoid installing all the trash of uneeded registry keys, drivers, connections, and services that this huge program install in the SO...)

2) Copy these files from the **VMWare Workstation** installation in the virtual OS to the host OS:

```
libeay32.dll
ssleay32.dll
vmware-vdiskmanager.exe
```

At this point we have a working standalone `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` that does not require the VMWare Workstation application installed to shrink a virtual-disk :), so we can store those files in a folder and call the application from commandline to shrink a disk:

```
".\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe" -k ".\Disk.vmdk"
```

Note: Those dll libraries are related to **OpenSSL** and are required to run the app, maybe other features of `vmware-vdiskmanager.exe` will require to copy other libraries.

3) Plus we can add some registry keys in our OS to shrink an VMWare virtual-disk (**disk.vmdk**) by doing mouse right-click on the file:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Classes\SystemFileAssociations\.VMDK\Shell\VMWare]
"MUIVerb"="VMWare"
"SubCommands"="VMWare.Compact"
"icon"="C:\\VMWare.ico"
"Position"="Top"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\VMWare.Compact]
@="Shrink Disk"
"icon"="C:\\VMWare.ico"

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CommandStore\shell\VMWare.Compact\command]
@="\"C:\\vmware-vdiskmanager.exe\" -k \"%1\""
```

Note: Change the filepaths on the registry script.