# How can I, Zerofree or otherwise, reclaim space from deleted files on a Linux VM under VMware?

Tags: linux, vmware

I have a VMware Player Linux Mint VM under Windows 10, and I want to free up space from files that I deleted but are still part of the disk file.

Existing discussion suggests that Zerofree, followed by compacting the disk file, will do what I want. The assertion was made that a virtual machine could be booted on a USB key, but I don't see exactly how to do that. I have, in the past, been able to mount VMware disks from another machine, but the options appear to be greyed out in Player.

Can I, with Player, boot from a Linux USB key (and have the disk file be accessible as something I can unmount and run zerofree), and if so how?

Can I, with Player, attach the hard drive I want to compact to another machine and run zerofree, and if so how?

Are any of these things sensitive to licensing, where something I want to do is available from a paid Pro license upgrade but not on the free, non-commercial license?

Thanks,

Comment: I think the easiest way to do this is to upgrade Player to Pro. Pro supports "vmware-toolbox-cmd disk shrink /" and I use this. The closest I could come to starting a VMDK file is this "https://communities.vmware.com/thread/640595" and it looks more complicated than I would like, especially if you need to use it on an ongoing basis (VMDK files need to be shrunk more than once)

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/611955/vmware-workstation-how-to-reduce-vmdk-maximum-size

Comment: That question (the SU answer referenced) (it appears to me) relates to Workstation (not Player) - at least it seems so. Newer (newest) Workstation versions include a Shrink capability as part of the Workstation product.